# Classification of representations of the lie algebra $\mathfrak{u(2)}$.

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, lie-algebras

The question is very direct, what is the list of irreducible representations of the real Lie algebra $\mathfrak{u(2)}$? Of course, you can simply answer the whole deal, but if you do, please explain as much as possible, but anyway I was thinking more of a reference.

I have found some confusing and poorly explained stuff about representation theory of the Lie group $U(2)$ (e.g. https://math.berkeley.edu/~teleman/math/RepThry.pdf), and of course, one can always differentiate reps of $U(2)$ to get reps of $\mathfrak{u}(2)$, but I don`t know if this is all of them (and if so, how to prove it).

Comment: Teleman discusses $\mathfrak{su}(2)$. For this see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2284240/irreducible-representations-of-su2-in-dimension-d-how-do-we-know-it-exists).